# SheetWrite Data in Columns

Tags: excel, cplex, opl

I am using OPL CPLEX 12.9 
and I want to write my results in an excel file. 
It is a two dimension array and I want to write the results in two columns but is it only possible to write the Data in lines?

Example Code in .dat 
Product_Cost to SheetWrite (Daten, "Result!A1:B10");

What can I write for A1:B10 to get the results in two columns?

Answer (score 1):

before doing SheetWrite you could transpose your matrix:

```
int M=2;
 int N=5;

 int A[i in 1..M][j in 1..N] = rand(4);

 int B [j in 1..N][i in 1..M]=A[i][j];

 execute
 {
 writeln("A=",A);
 writeln("B=",B);
 }
```

gives

```
A= [[0 0 0 0 1]
         [3 2 3 2 0]]
B= [[0 3]
         [0 2]
         [0 3]
         [0 2]
         [1 0]]
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I add all my Data with SheetRead from excel.

Comment: If you transpose before SheetWrite you can turn columns into rows and conversely